# Monitoring Java-Runtime / Virgo Server with Shell Script

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to create a script that monitors a java runtime process,which makes use of a Virgo service. It should start the process when its not running. As there is no specific service name, i was thinking of grepping the name of the process and use it as an identifier.

Here is the code i thought of:

```
#!/bin/sh

service=virgo

ps auxw | grep $service | grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        /opt/apromore/ApromoreCode/build.xml start-virgo > /dev/null
    else
        echo Apromore is running already
fi
```

and this is the process I try to monitor (value from ps aux)

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -classpath usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/                usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar -Dant.home=/usr/                               share/ant -Dant.library.dir=/usr/share/ant/lib org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launc                               her -cp  start-virgo

but even when the process is running, i cant identify it with the mentioned script. There is a error called $'\r'. I have no idea how to get rid of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with _even when the service is running i cant identify it there is a problem called $"\r" and with the proof_. Also, try to avoid posting images; instead, put text.